# Ignore uninitialized objects during normalization

Tags: php, symfony

I've been reading the Serializer documentation and couldn't find anything to ignore uninitialized objects during normalization. I don't know if it exists, but there could be a flag to indicate that we don't want uninitialized objects to be included during normalization.

```php
class User
{
    public string $name;

    public Address $address;
}

class Address
{
    public string $street;
}

$data = [
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'address' => '',
];

$denormalized = $this->denormalizer->denormalize($data, User::class);
$normalized = $this->normalizer->normalize($denormalized);

// Actual Result
$data = [
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'address' => [],
];

// Expected Result
$normalized = [
    'name' => 'John Doe'
];
```

Comment: Does it also happen when `'address' => NULL` ?